# trouble logging in to rails app after logout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, authentication

This community looks great.  I'm new to rails so please bear with some confusion.  I have an app that lets a new user signup.  The user gets created along with a wallet object that obtains a foreign key that matches the users given primary key.  When I click logout, I return to the intended page, but all of a sudden, I am being thrown an "invalid combination" error... I feel like ever since I introduced the current_user helper method, that it's been throwing something off.  Here are pieces of my files

The session's controller

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
    skip_before_action :require_login, only: [:new, :create]


  def new

  end

 def create
    @user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
    if @user && @user.authenticate(params[:password])
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      redirect_to "/users/#{@user.id}"
    else 
      flash[:errors] = ["Invalid Combination"]
      redirect_to "/sessions/new"
    end
  end

  def destroy
    session.delete(:user_id)
    redirect_to "/sessions/new"
  end

end
```

The user's controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :require_login, only: [:new, :create]
  before_action :require_correct_user, only: [:edit, :show, :update, :destroy]

  def new

  end

  def show
    @user = User.includes(:wallet).find_by_id(params[:id])
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @user = User.create user_params 
    @wallet = Wallet.new
    @wallet.save
    @user.wallet_id = @wallet.id
    @wallet.user = @user
    if @user.save && @wallet.save
      session[:user_id] = @user.id

      redirect_to "/users/#{@user.id}"
    else
      flash[:errors] = @user.errors.full_messages + @wallet.errors.full_messages
      redirect_to "/sessions/new"
    end

  end

  private
    def require_correct_user
      if current_user != User.find(params[:id])
        redirect_to "/users/#{session[:user_id]}"
      end
        end


def user_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:email, :motto, :bio, :first_name, 
:last_name, 
:password, :password_confirmation)
    end

end
```

And finally, here's the view I am directing to for both new signups and existing users login (sessions#new).  Please let me know where you see any potential hiccups! Thanks!

```
    <nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
        <a href="#" class="brand-logo center">
        <%=image_tag("straightupLogoSiteHome.png")%></a>
        <ul id="nav-mobile" class="left hide-on-med-and-down">
        </ul>
        <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
        </ul>
        <ul class="side-nav" id="mobile-demo">
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="container">
    <br><br>
    <div class="row">
        <h3 class="center light">SIMPLE P2P BETTING</h3>
        <br><br><br>
        <div class="col s5 push-s7">
            <H5 class="light">OR PLEASE... JOIN US</H5>
            <form action="/users" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="<%= form_authenticity_token %>">
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                    <input type="text" id="Email" name = "user[email]">
                    <label for="Email">EMAIL</label>
                </div>
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                    <input type="text" id="Motto" name = "user[motto]">
                    <label for="Motto">YOUR MOTTO (OPTIONAL)</label>
                </div>
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                    <input type="text" id="Bio" name = "user[bio]">
                    <label for="Bio">A BIO (OPTIONAL)</label>
                </div>
                <div class="input-field col s6">
                    <input type="text" id="First_Name" name = "user[first_name]">
                    <label for="First_Name">FIRST NAME</label>
                </div>
                <div class="input-field col s6">
                    <input type="text" id="Last_Name" name = "user[last_name]">
                    <label for="Last_Name">HOUSE NAME</label>
                </div>
                <div class="input-field col s6">
                    <input type="text" id="Password" name = "user[password]">
                    <label for="Password">PASSWORD</label>
                </div>
                <div class="input-field col s6">
                    <input type="text" id="Password_Confirmation" name = "user[password_confirmation]">
                    <label for="Password_Confirmation">AND AGAIN!</label>
                </div>
                <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn"><input type="submit" name="Join" value="JOIN US"></a>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="col s4 pull-s4">
            <H5 class="light">LOG BACK IN. sorry...</H5>
            <form action="/sessions" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="<%= 
form_authenticity_token %>">
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                    <input type="text" id="Email" name = "user[email]">
                    <label for="Email">EMAIL</label>
                </div>
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                    <input type="text" id="Password" name = "user[password]">
                    <label for="Password">PASSWORD</label>
                </div>
                <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn"><input type="submit" name="login" value="Login"></a>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Aplogies. The current_user is defined in the applications_controller below.  Thanks!

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
# Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
# For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
    protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end

  helper_method :current_user

  def authorize
    redirect_to "/sessions/new" unless current_user
  end
end
```

Comment: Please update your question with the `current_user` definition.

Comment: Maybe have something to do with the `session[:user_id]`. Have you check `session` and `params` in your `require_correct_user`?

Comment: `logger.debug "params[:id]: #{params[:id]}, session[:user_id]: #{session[:user_id]}"` at the beginning of `require_correct_user` would be fine.

Comment: Could you explain where I put that exactly and why I need it?  It doesn't look like it goes within the before_action.

Comment: because doing it like this doesn't work.  I have no idea what logger is and this isn't the right syntax it appears if just put at the top of the def...

Comment: Put the line after `def require_correct_user` and before `if current_user != User.find(params[:id])`

Comment: I figured it out.  Refer to my answer if interested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.  The issue was here... The answer I received was a bit of a workaround which is not at all what I need when I'm learning.  So in my sessions_controller, I was defining a user by the params specified for the user in the users_controller.  What I needed to do was define say login_params within the sessions_controller.. either that or in the create method .find_by_email(params[user.email]).  I chose to create this private method at the bottom and changed the 
.find_by_email(params[:email]) and the authenticate(params[:password]) 
to
.find_by_email(login_params[:email]) and the authenticate(login_params[:password])

```
 private

  def login_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password)
  end
```